# Gnupg secp256k1 signature does not match other implementations

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, elliptic-curve-crypto

I am trying to make the gpg agent sign for cryptocurrency purposes. I've tried signing a couple of hashes, and the signature of **one** of them gets a *different* `r` while getting the same `s` than other implementations.

I've compared the result with the `elliptic` nodejs library and `libsecp256k1` in c, which match each other's results.

Presumably these an obvious and silly error on my part that's the reason for this, but I can't spot it myself.

Here is the c source for the `libsecp256k1` version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <secp256k1.h>

const unsigned char msg[32] = {0xc3, 0xaf, 0xca, 0x60, 0x84, 0xa5, 0x8f, 0x5b, 0x06, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x4a, 0xaa, 0x6e, 0xd9, 0x06, 0x3a, 0x9b, 0xa7, 0x0f, 0x2b, 0xd4, 0xa7, 0x68, 0xf4, 0xad, 0x41, 0x41, 0x74, 0x28, 0xf8, 0x02};
const unsigned char pk[32] = {0xEC, 0x5D, 0xCC, 0xE1, 0x3E, 0xA0, 0xC5, 0xF4, 0x50, 0x0C, 0x31, 0x5C, 0x96, 0x4C, 0xDE, 0xE1, 0x0A, 0x05, 0x53, 0x13, 0xEA, 0x71, 0xB7, 0x55, 0x82, 0x00, 0xE9, 0x8B, 0x1D, 0xF7, 0x7F, 0x38};


int main() {
    int r;
    int fd;
    secp256k1_context *ctx;
    secp256k1_ecdsa_signature sig;
    unsigned char *serialized_signature;

    ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN);
    r = secp256k1_ecdsa_sign(ctx, &sig, (const unsigned char*)msg, (const unsigned char*)pk, NULL, NULL);
    if (r != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    serialized_signature = malloc(64);  
    r = secp256k1_ecdsa_signature_serialize_compact(ctx, serialized_signature, &sig);
    if (r != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite(serialized_signature, 1, 64, stdout);
    free(serialized_signature);
    secp256k1_context_destroy(ctx);

    return 0;
}

---

outputs:
$ ./a.out | hexdump -C
00000000  26 0d c8 ab 01 f0 79 64  0b dd 8d 5b 5b 43 76 bd  |&.....yd...[[Cv.|
00000010  d2 db 1d 66 fa ce 87 57  6e f1 1f 04 df 54 24 67  |...f...Wn....T$g|
00000020  0f 50 01 c3 3c 17 b5 5e  a1 c7 dc cb 2a 38 af 69  |.P..<..^....*8.i|
00000030  7c a1 8e 38 48 6c b4 7a  9b d7 f3 24 c9 99 17 b3  ||..8Hl.z...$....|
```

Here is the attempt using gnupg:

```
keyid=D5C4AD7CC2A40CA64860ACA504450BED5A1D56D6
keygrip=A6D4B5C57143CE15C07D0DDEA5986B13B5F7ED72
hsh=c3afca6084a58f5b060d0a4aaa6ed9063a9ba70f2bd4a768f4ad41417428f802

cat <<EOF | gpg --import
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

lHQEXs4mIhMFK4EEAAoCAwTZvUk3CNXg/KYqfIbkNkZZXeD+yBE5X7AJ7IEYkpA9
SSks1IOQqws0M3U7YhhJt6sgsBQSjR9y/kUHHSSXHjRjAAEA7F3M4T6gxfRQDDFc
lkze4QoFUxPqcbdVggDpix33fzgPtbQgTWVsdmluIGVyZCA8bWVsdmluQHNlY2hv
c3QuaW5mbz6IkAQTEwgAOBYhBNXErXzCpAymSGCspQRFC+1aHVbWBQJeziYiAhsD
BQsJCAcDBRUKCQgLBRYCAwEAAh4BAheAAAoJEARFC+1aHVbWTzoA/AqL6dSHIr0+
lfRNSSo1a2WiKZpnCna9j9Kiiv7UylMqAQDCXnK+2gZM9xPsXOe0jrCyvc2qhqMN
/X5TObkVg5f1jg==
=OhY5
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
EOF

gpg-connect-agent <<EOF | hexdump -C
SIGKEY $keygrip
SETHASH --hash=sha256 $hsh
PKSIGN
EOF

---

outputs:

$ bash agent-sign.sh 
gpg: key 04450BED5A1D56D6: "Melvin erd <melvin@sechost.info>" not changed
gpg: key 04450BED5A1D56D6: secret key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
00000000  4f 4b 0a 4f 4b 0a 44 20  28 37 3a 73 69 67 2d 76  |OK.OK.D (7:sig-v|
00000010  61 6c 28 35 3a 65 63 64  73 61 28 31 3a 72 33 32  |al(5:ecdsa(1:r32|
00000020  3a 26 25 30 44 c8 ab 01  f0 79 64 0b dd 8d 5b 5b  |:&%0D....yd...[[|
00000030  43 76 bd d2 db 1d 66 fa  ce 87 57 6e f1 1f 04 df  |Cv....f...Wn....|
00000040  54 24 67 29 28 31 3a 73  33 32 3a 0f 50 01 c3 3c  |T$g)(1:s32:.P..<|
00000050  17 b5 5e a1 c7 dc cb 2a  38 af 69 7c a1 8e 38 48  |..^....*8.i|..8H|
00000060  6c b4 7a 9b d7 f3 24 c9  99 17 b3 29 29 29 0a 4f  |l.z...$....))).O|
00000070  4b 0a                                             |K.|
00000072

(signature itself; r at 0x21 and, s at `0x4b`)
```

Answer (score 3):

The gpg secp256k1 curve symbolic expression (S-EXP) output results displayed in the hex dump (from the gpg script, second program at the bottom of the question posted above). The 0x28 "(", and 0x29 ")" represent parenthesis that frame the 32 byte S-EXP encoding of the R & S signature components.

**`libsecp256k1 Code Output:`**

**R Signature Component =** 26 0d c8 ab 01 f0 79 64 0b dd 8d 5b 5b 43 76 bd d2 db 1d 66 fa ce 87 57 6e f1 1f 04 df 54 24 67

**S Signature Component =** 0f 50 01 c3 3c 17 b5 5e a1 c7 dc cb 2a 38 af 69 7c a1 8e 38 48 6c b4 7a  9b d7 f3 24 c9 99 17 b3

**`GPG Script S-EXP Output:`**

**R Signature Component =** 26 **25 30 44** c8 ab 01 f0 79 64 0b dd 8d 5b 5b 43 76 bd d2 db 1d 66 fa ce 87 57 6e f1 1f 04 df 54 24 67

**S Signature Component =** 0f 50 01 c3 3c 17 b5 5e a1 c7 dc cb 2a 38 af 69 7c a1 8e 38 48 6c b4 7a 9b d7 f3 24 c9 99 17 b3

The S signature components appear to match the results at the libsecp256k1 output exactly.  Only the second byte of the R components seem to differ, but it is worth noting %0D decoding of "25 30 44" from the S-EXP sure looks like the 0x0d second output byte output of the R component of the 1st program.

% cat melvin_5a1d56d6.asc

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

lHQEXs4mIhMFK4EEAAoCAwTZvUk3CNXg/KYqfIbkNkZZXeD+yBE5X7AJ7IEYkpA9
SSks1IOQqws0M3U7YhhJt6sgsBQSjR9y/kUHHSSXHjRjAAEA7F3M4T6gxfRQDDFc
lkze4QoFUxPqcbdVggDpix33fzgPtbQgTWVsdmluIGVyZCA8bWVsdmluQHNlY2hv
c3QuaW5mbz6IkAQTEwgAOBYhBNXErXzCpAymSGCspQRFC+1aHVbWBQJeziYiAhsD
BQsJCAcDBRUKCQgLBRYCAwEAAh4BAheAAAoJEARFC+1aHVbWTzoA/AqL6dSHIr0+
lfRNSSo1a2WiKZpnCna9j9Kiiv7UylMqAQDCXnK+2gZM9xPsXOe0jrCyvc2qhqMN
/X5TObkVg5f1jg==
=OhY5
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Notice how the last output (S Signature Component) computed by gpg differs from the manual calculation below that applies a Bitcoin secp256k1 signature:

% cat melvin_5a1d56d6.asc | gpg --list-packets --verbose

```
# off=0 ctb=94 tag=5 hlen=2 plen=116
:secret key packet:
    version 4, algo 19, created 1590568482, expires 0
    pkey[0]: 052B8104000A secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)
    pkey[1]: 04D9BD493708D5E0FCA62A7C86E43646595DE0FEC811395FB009EC811892903D49292CD48390AB0B3433753B621849B7AB20B014128D1F72FE45071D24971E3463
    skey[2]: EC5DCCE13EA0C5F4500C315C964CDEE10A055313EA71B7558200E98B1DF77F38
    checksum: 0fb5
    keyid: 04450BED5A1D56D6
# off=118 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=32
:user ID packet: "Melvin erd <melvin@sechost.info>"
# off=152 ctb=88 tag=2 hlen=2 plen=144
:signature packet: algo 19, keyid 04450BED5A1D56D6
    version 4, created 1590568482, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 8, begin of digest 4f 3a
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 D5C4AD7CC2A40CA64860ACA504450BED5A1D56D6)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2020-05-27)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 4 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 3)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 4 (pref-hash-algos: 10 9 8 11)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 4 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1 0)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 04450BED5A1D56D6)
    data: 0A8BE9D48722BD3E95F44D492A356B65A2299A670A76BD8FD2A28AFED4CA532A
    data: C25E72BEDA064CF713EC5CE7B48EB0B2BDCDAA86A30DFD7E5339B9158397F58E
```

```
% cat melvin_5a1d56d6.asc | sed 's/\[GNUPG:\].*$//' | sed 's/-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----//' | sed 's/-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----//' | sed 's/-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----//' | sed 's/-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----//' | sed 's/-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----//' | sed 's/-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----//' | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/^=.*$/d' |  tr -d '\n' | bx base64-decode | bx base16-encode
```

```
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
```

**1. ECC Secret-Key Packet (Tag 5): 0x94**
Raw Packet: 9474045ece262213052b8104000a020304d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463000100ec5dcce13ea0c5f4500c315c964cdee10a055313ea71b7558200e98b1df77f380fb5

% echo -n 045ece262213052b8104000a020304d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463 | wc -c

```
 158 / 2 = 79 = 0x004f
```

**$MasterFingerprintBasis =** 99004f045ece262213052b8104000a020304d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463

**2. User ID Packet       (Tag 13): 0xb4**
Raw Packet: b4204d656c76696e20657264203c6d656c76696e40736563686f73742e696e666f3e

% echo -n 4d656c76696e20657264203c6d656c76696e40736563686f73742e696e666f3e | wc -c

```
  64 / 2 = 32 = 0x00000020
```

**$UserIDFingerprintBasis =** b4000000204d656c76696e20657264203c6d656c76696e40736563686f73742e696e666f3e

**3. ECC Signature Packet  (Tag 2): 0x88**
Raw Packet: 8890041313080038162104d5c4ad7cc2a40ca64860aca504450bed5a1d56d605025ece2622021b03050b0908070305150a09080b051602030100021e01021780000a091004450bed5a1d56d64f3a00fc0a8be9d48722bd3e95f44d492a356b65a2299a670a76bd8fd2a28afed4ca532a0100c25e72beda064cf713ec5ce7b48eb0b2bdcdaa86a30dfd7e5339b9158397f58e

% echo -n 041313080038162104d5c4ad7cc2a40ca64860aca504450bed5a1d56d605025ece2622021b03050b0908070305150a09080b051602030100021e01021780 | wc -c

```
 124 / 2 = 62 = 0x0000003e
```

**$MasterMagicBasis       =** 041313080038162104d5c4ad7cc2a40ca64860aca504450bed5a1d56d605025ece2622021b03050b0908070305150a09080b051602030100021e0102178004ff0000003e

**4. SHA256( $MasterFingerprintBasis + $UserIDFingerprintBasis + $MasterMagicBasis )**

% echo 99004f045ece262213052b8104000a020304d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463b4000000204d656c76696e20657264203c6d656c76696e40736563686f73742e696e666f3e041313080038162104d5c4ad7cc2a40ca64860aca504450bed5a1d56d605025ece2622021b03050b0908070305150a09080b051602030100021e0102178004FF0000003e | bx sha256
**4f3a4cc1a8f4bea91ddca5688b73b9379edd80876a1b5ed47543f33939f3b7cf**

**5. Sign Computed Hash**

./btc_sign_secp256k1 -k EC5DCCE13EA0C5F4500C315C964CDEE10A055313EA71B7558200E98B1DF77F38 -m 4f3a4cc1a8f4bea91ddca5688b73b9379edd80876a1b5ed47543f33939f3b7cf

```
 secp256k1 Uncompressed Pubkey : 04d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463

 Message is binary encoded as HEX        : 4f3a4cc1a8f4bea91ddca5688b73b9379edd80876a1b5ed47543f33939f3b7cf
         secp256k1 R Signature Component : 0a8be9d48722bd3e95f44d492a356b65a2299a670a76bd8fd2a28afed4ca532a
         secp256k1 S Signature Component : 3da18d4125f9b308ec13a3184b714f4bfce132600c3aa2bd6c98a5774c9e4bb3
```

Now let's compute the complementary signature that does not require one to have the private keys to compute.  The complement signature to (r1,s1) will be (r1,s2) where "s1+s2=n" and for the sep256k1 curve n = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141.

% echo 3da18d4125f9b308ec13a3184b714f4bfce132600c3aa2bd6c98a5774c9e4bb3 | tr "a-f" "A-F"

`3DA18D4125F9B308EC13A3184B714F4BFCE132600C3AA2BD6C98A5774C9E4BB3`

% echo "obase=16; ibase=16; FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141 - 3DA18D4125F9B308EC13A3184B714F4BFCE132600C3AA2BD6C98A5774C9E4BB3" | bc

`C25E72BEDA064CF713EC5CE7B48EB0B2BDCDAA86A30DFD7E5339B9158397F58E`

Using the value of s2 computed above, it is possible to maleate the signature unless conventions are picked to get rid of the mathematical signature ambiguity and specify a conventionally correct signature such that s1 < s2 as Bitcoin did.  With Bitcoin, this was a prior form of "transaction malleability". With OpenPGP, this could potentially leads to a form of "certificate malleability" that gets exacerbated with multiple signatures being part of a public key block. For OpenPGP, the interoperability consensus rules are documented an IETF RFC [**under development**](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-openpgp-crypto-refresh-02.txt) that currently makes no mention of countermeasures for certificate malleability.

Additional Info:

The secret key below can be found towards the tail end of the the secret packet above.  The uncompressed public key (essentially twice as long as the associated compressed public key) can be computed as shown with the resulting public key being the shaded output of **A%**. Dropping the "-u" argument forces the computation of the associated uncompressed public key, a shorter answer that is not currently applicable to GPG.

**A%** echo ec5dcce13ea0c5f4500c315c964cdee10a055313ea71b7558200e98b1df77f38 | [bx **ec-to-public**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-ec-to-public) -u

`04d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463`

**B%** echo 99004f045ece262213052b8104000a020304d9bd493708d5e0fca62a7c86e43646595de0fec811395fb009ec811892903d49292cd48390ab0b3433753b621849b7ab20b014128d1f72fe45071d24971e3463 | [bx **base16-decode**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-base16-decode) | shasum -

`d5c4ad7cc2a40ca64860aca504450bed5a1d56d6  -`

Comment: Although the S values are different, they are both valid signatures because they are additive inverses mod n i.e. s2 = -s1 mod n -- and [libsecp256k1 does 'low-s' signatures as required by bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59820/sign-a-tx-with-low-s-value-using-openssl)

Comment: Is this related to why gpg does not natively support secp256k1 signature and authentication subkeys? (signature malleability)

Comment: So secp256k1 OpenPGP certs can suffer from certificate malleability if there are two acceptable certs for each signature unless a convention like Bitcoin is applied?

Comment: The exact value of a PGP signed key (historically not called a certificate, although semantically that name is valid and in recent years seems to be more common) doesn't matter only whether it is valid. My GPG 2.2.4 _does_ support secp256k1 as well as secp{256,384,521}r1 and Brainpool, which all use the same ECDSA algorithm (plus Ed25519 which does not). PGP programs usually identify keys by keyid (and GPG alternatively by keygrip) both of which depend only on the actual key packet (or value) not the signature(s), partly because the set of signatures on a PGP key often varies over time. ...

Comment: ... X.509 _could_ have a problem here, because it is fairly common to identify an X.509 cert by its hash (aka fingerprint), but AFAICT any failure would be safe, i.e. it would never result in trusting a bad cert, only failing to trust a good (but malleated) one.
 AFAIK Bitcoin is the only application that _depended_ (and only sometimes) on the signature bytes being identical.

Comment: According to https://ristretto.group/why_ristretto.html#pitfalls-of-a-cofactor, signature malleability for regular ed25519 appears to be 4 times worse than that of secp256k1.